# Oracle APEX, create & save (insert) from Interactive Report page to DML Form

Tags: oracle-apex

Need a help in understand underline logic here. I have created a simple APEX application. First page shows the table details and via a "Create" button "Interactive Search" region, directs to a form page. Now form page consists of "Save" and "Insert" buttons in correct regions. So whole app works. When I press "Create" from 1st page to 2nd, "Save" button is invisible and when I click the edit icon on the table of 1st page, "Create" button is invisible in 2nd. App works accordingly, but could not figure out what setting enable this set-up even though I was able to make it work.
1st Page : Interactive Report Page. 2nd Page : DML Form. Built the app from blank pages.
Could any of you explain how it works?

Answer (score 1):

When you click the <kbd>Create</kbd> button on the Interactive Report page, it takes you to the Form page in *insert* mode, i.e. it allows you to enter a **new** row into the table. Therefore, the Form page has the <kbd>Create</kbd> (and the <kbd>Cancel</kbd>) button.

On the other hand, when you click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button on the Interactive Report, it takes you to the same Form page, but this time in *edit* mode which enables you to modify values (and save those changes with the <kbd>Apply Changes / Save</kbd> button), delete that row using the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button, or - as previously <kbd>Cancel</kbd> current operation.

If you look at Form page's buttons' properties, you'll see that they have *Server-side Conditions* set which are then used to render (or not) a certain button. For example, if the Form page number is 13 and the *primary key column* is set to the `ID` column, then these conditions look like this:

- <kbd>Create</kbd>: `P13_ID IS NULL` (i.e. the *primary key column* value doesn't exist yet, which means that this is a brand new row)
- <kbd>Apply Chanages / Save</kbd>: `P13_ID IS NOT NULL` (i.e. the *primary key column* value exists, which means that row you see was fetched from the database)
- <kbd>Delete</kbd>: `P13_ID IS NOT NULL` (the same condition as for the <kbd>Apply Chanages / Save</kbd> button)
- <kbd>Cancel</kbd>: it is always displayed.